# Do any non-second-declension neuter nouns end in m?

Tags: declension, noun, neuter

I have the impression that the ending *-m* appears on neuter nouns (in the nominative/accusative form) only in the second declension, but I don't know whether there are any exceptions. Is there any example of a neuter noun ending in *-m* that belongs to a declension other than the second?

I know that Latin nouns sometimes had multiple declension patterns or multiple genders. For the purpose of this question, I'd accept a word that belongs to multiple declensions/genders, as long as it's clear that the neuter nominative/accusative form ending in *-m* isn't just part of a complete regular second-declension paradigm.

If no such words exist, I would be interested in knowing whether there is any etymological explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [**Bethlehem**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DBethlehem), n., indecl. Though a borrowing, clearly does not belong to the second declension. Note that there is also the alternative **Bethlehemum, -i**, which does belong to the 2nd.

I suspect there are no native Latin words, but it's just a suspicion with no etymological explanation. I'm certain other users could help with that. We have a number of experts in PIE here)

Comment: If you're looking for the etymology, it's from Hebrew _beith leħem_, "house of bread".

Comment: Thanks! Even though the -m here clearly does not originate from the Indo-European -m suffix, there's the interesting mention of the adjective "Bethlaeus" where the "m" is removed, which suggests to me that Romans might not have necessarily felt a strong distinction between word-final -m here and in other words.

Answer (score 5):

The etymological explanation (which of course only takes the question a stage further back) is that in PIE, thematic inanimate nouns had the nom./acc. sg. ending *-om, while athematic inanimate nouns had a zero ending. The former became Latin second-declension neuters, the latter third-declension neuters.

This is only a partial explanation in that one might have expected some athematic inanimates with a stem ending in -m to have survived in the Latin third declension, but if there were any such nouns, none seem to have survived into Latin.

Answer (score 4):

I hadn't noticed this when I posted the question, but it turned out that the [Wiktionary list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_neuter_nouns_in_the_third_declension) that I mentioned in the original question contained at least one genuine word of interest. The word *jūgerum/iūgerum* is a second-declension form, but it seems that in the plural oblique cases we almost always see third-declension forms (*jūgerum* and *jūgeribus*; with *jūgerīs* as an alternative ablative form attested in Varro's *Res Rusticae*). This is confirmed by the [Lewis and Short entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=jugerum).

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iugerum#Latin) says that there is no attested third-declension singular nominative/accusative form.